# Google Domains Github pages Enforce HTTPS — Unavailable for your site because your domain is not properly configured to support HTTPS

Tags: https, github-pages, static-site, google-domain-api

I have published a static site through github pages. I can access it through `https://www.<sitename>.github.io`. Now that I am trying to use a custom domain name provisioned through google domains, I cannot Enforce site access through HTTPS and get the following error `Enforce HTTPS — Unavailable for your site because your domain is not properly configured to support HTTPS`. I am using these IPs for setting up the custom domain record on google domain

1. 185.199.111.153
2. 185.199.110.153
3. 185.199.109.153
4. 185.199.108.153

Has anyone faced this situtation before? Would appreciate any insights into the situation

Comment: Where do you get the IP addresses from?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating A name records pointing to the IP addresses, I fixed this issue by creating two CNAME records. One for the root of my domain to my <username>.github.io. The other record is the www subdomain to my root domain. This fixed the issue for me.

I am using Cloudflare, but this should work similarly for you.

[Github docs reference](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site)